# how getline works in this code

Tags: c++11, getline

```
    int function1(string data){
        stringstream ss(data);
        return function2(ss);
    }
    int function2(stringstream& ss){
        string val;
        getline(ss,val,',');
        return stoi(val);
    }
```

If I change function2 to

```
    int function2(stringstream ss){...}
```

It doesn't work. I would like to know why? 
The compliation error is

use of deleted function 'std::basic_stringstream<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_stringstream(const std::basic_stringstream<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator]'

And another question is I am curious about how getline actually works. Like the code below:

```
    while(!getline(ss,val,','))
        cout<<val;
```

how does getline keep track of the position of iterator after one iteration?

Comment: Explain "doesn't work"? Are you getting a compiler error or a runtime error?

Comment: `getline()` is not responsible for the position in the _**stream**_ (hint).

Comment: @DavidThomas could you explain more? I really have no idea

Comment: You say that when you change `function2` to take `stringstream ss`, it doesn't work.  What precisely tells you it doesn't work?  Does the code compile?  Or does it fail when you run your program?

Comment: @DavidThomas updated the error!

Comment: So the compiler is telling you "you can't do that!".  You are attempting to call the copy constructor that has been _deleted_.  The designer of stringstream doesn't allow stringstreams to be copied (only moved).  Prior to the change, you we passing a reference to a stringstream - which does not require a copy operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you try to copy the `ss` stream and copy method is deleted using (Relatively) new C++ syntax, so the error occurs.

You're not allowing to copy stream, so you want to give it to a function, you must use reference.

You can find some information about

- deleted function : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions
- stringstream constructor : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/

Answer (score 1):

Defining `int function2(stringstream ss)` would require the use of the deleted copy constructor on `stringstream`.  `stringstream` has deleted the copy constructor and copy assignment operator. `streamstream` does allow moves.

`getline()` does not track the stream.  `stringstream`'s class definition derives from a `streambuf` which is responsible for this minutiae/details.